# OpenSSL in app store app

Tags: c++, macos, openssl, app-store

I'm developing some application for Mac OS X which is going to use my library written on C++ with OpenSSL. I'm quite new with Mac OS and have yet no experience with it's markets so my question is quite simple: can I sell the application on app store which uses library written on C++ with OpenSSL? Will it not be rejected? And what are the alternatives to OpenSSL on Mac Os X in this case? Thank you very much for your answers!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because its a vendor store question. Please see [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/608639). Android questions could be on-topic at [Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange](http://android.stackexchange.com/); while Apple questions could be on-topic at [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenSSL, you just need to statically link the version you wish to use into your binary.

The alternatives are Security and Common Crypto, Apple's [Security](https://developer.apple.com/security/) page provides a high-level overview with links.

HTH